# Javafx webview not displaying dash-plotly app on run

Tags: java, python, javafx, plotly-dash, javafx-webengine

I am trying to integrate a Dash-plotly application into a Java application.

I have created a Plotly-Dash app that looks like this:

The Dash app component of the code is like this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

##image_filename = 'tmp.png' # replace with your own image
##encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(image_filename, 'rb').read())

styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='basic-interactions', figure=fig)
        ], className="seven columns"),

        html.Div([
             dcc.Markdown("""
                **Node Details**

                Click node to view details here.
            """),
            html.Pre(id='click-data', style={"maxHeight": "500px", "overflow": "scroll"}),
        ], className="four columns"),
    ], className="row")
])

@app.callback(
    Output('click-data', 'children'),
    Input('basic-interactions', 'clickData'))
def display_click_data(clickData):
    mydict = ast.literal_eval('{}'.format(clickData))
    if mydict!=None:
        print_clicked = mydict['points'][0]['text']
        for i in full_texts:
            if print_clicked == i[0]:
                print_clicked = i[1]

        if '<br>' in print_clicked:
            print_clicked = print_clicked.replace('<br>','\n')
        if '<b>' in print_clicked:
            print_clicked = print_clicked.replace('<b>','**')
        if '</b>' in print_clicked:
            print_clicked = print_clicked.replace('</b>','**')
        return print_clicked


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1',port=8050,debug=True)
```

I have also created a Java program that takes in user inputs and uses a javafx WebView panel to display the Dash-app in a java application.

The javafx component of the code is like this:

```
private void setGraph(JPanel pane, String title) throws Exception
{
    pane.removeAll();
    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add(jfxPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        
        boolean result=false;
        while(result==false) {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8050);
                result=true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not listen on port: " + 8050);
                // ...
            }
        }
        if (result ==true) {
             webEngine.load("http://127.0.0.1:8050");
             root.getChildren().add(webView);
             jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }
        
    });
    pane.updateUI();
        
}
```

However, when I **run the Java code for the first time**, the Dash app created at http://127.0.0.1:8050 does not show. (The Dash app can be seen on a normal chrome browser though)

When I **run the Java code a second time**, the Dash app shows up, only because the dash application started in the first run did not terminate.

I have verified that the Javafx panel segment of my Java program runs after the Python code that build the Dash app runs.

My problems:

1. I am unsure why it does not show the Dash-app when I run the code the first time and how to solve it...
2. How do I terminate the Dash app for every time I execute the program?

I have been stuck on this for too long... Any suggestions would be much appreciated.